# Getting a KeyError when passing data to a Wizard in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, wizard

i'm using a context to send data to my wizard, but i always get this error "KeyError: 'default_new_name"

i tried doing the example [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/solved-how-to-pass-current-values-to-wizard-in-odoo-110946) but still getting the same error
here's my code

## model creating a wizard

```
@api.multi
def open_x2m_matrix(self):

    wiz = self.env['x2m.matrix.demo.wiz'].create({})
    return {
        'name': self.name,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'x2m.matrix.demo.wiz',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': wiz.id,
        'context': self.env.context,
        'context': {'default_new_name': self.name},
    }
```

## model creating 2d matrix

```
line_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'x2m.demo.line', default=lambda self: self._default_line_ids())
def _default_line_ids(self):
    recs =self.env['x2m.demo'].search([("name","!=",self._context['default_new_name'])])
    # same with users
    users = self.env['x2m.demo.line'].search([]).mapped('new_user_id')
    return [
        (0, 0, {
            'demo_id': rec.id,
            'new_user_id': usr.id,
            'value': 0,
        })
        # if the project doesn't have a task for the user, create a new one
        if not rec.line_ids.filtered(lambda x: x.new_user_id == usr) else
        # otherwise, return the task
        (4, rec.line_ids.filtered(lambda x: x.new_user_id == usr)[0].id)
        for rec in recs
        for usr in users
    ]
```

Comment: Does the filed `new_name` exist in the `x2m.matrix.demo.wiz` model? By the way, you cannot use two keys with the same name in a dictionary. You should create a copy of the frozen dictionary `context`, update the first one to add your `default_new_name` key to it, and then, send it in the returned dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` is already calling the default method for `line_ids`. So you should either don't create a wizard record and just call without an ID or you create it with your context flag on the right line:

1. open wizard without creating one

```py
@api.multi
def open_x2m_matrix(self):
    context = dict(self.env.context or {})
    context.update({'default_new_name': self.name})
    return {
        'name': self.name,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'x2m.matrix.demo.wiz',
        'target': 'new',
        # 'res_id': wiz.id,  # not needed
        'context': context
    }
```

2. use your context flag on creation, because that's the call where it's really needed

```py
@api.multi
def open_x2m_matrix(self):

    wiz = self.env['x2m.matrix.demo.wiz'].with_context(
        default_new_name=self.name).create({})
    return {
        'name': self.name,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'x2m.matrix.demo.wiz',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': wiz.id,
        'context': self.env.context,
    }
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see the with_context solution, one think when you create a record in a wizard i think the buttons will be disabled ?

Comment: thanks for the answer all of the solution is working you save my life